# DotNetOpenAuth Open Id Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

When using an OpenId provider, based on any examples I've seen the client application will always do this

```
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl /* Forms Auth will add this when it meets a page that needs authorization and redirects */)
    {
        IAuthenticationResponse response = _openId.GetResponse();


        if (response == null)
        {
            return HandleNeedOpenIdScenario();
        }
        else
        {
            return HandleOpenIdProviderSendingAssertion(response, returnUrl);
        }

    }
```

`HandleNeedOpenIdScenario` will bounce you over to the authentication server, where you will log in and eventually be sent back to `http://clientApp/Account/Login` where `_openId.GetResponse()` will not be null.

My question is:  What's happening in that `GetResponse()` method?  I can see that a request is made to my OpenId server at `http://openIdServerApp/user/my.account@email.com/` and that a 200 response is generated with the XRDS information.  But what's actually going on?  How does this call prove that I am who I say I am?

(I've looked at the source, but frankly, it's beyond my understanding.)

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: its basicaly just checking if you have valid cookies that already show that you are authenticated .  Try the same thing in an incognito browser window

Comment: Can you provide me with a reference for where you have seen code like this please.

Comment: Sure -- it looks like you wrote it, so I hope I didn't misrepresent:  https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/blob/master/src/OpenID/OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc/Controllers/UserController.cs